# LINQ Initializer Throws a "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager."

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
        DataLayer.Image image = new DataLayer.Image();
        image.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        image.ImageData = (byte[])Session[STR_UploadedImage];
        image.TimeStamp = imageDateTimeUserControl.DateTime;
        image.Incident_Id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString[STR_IncidentId]);
        image.CreatedBy_Id = db.Employees.First(em => em.Username == Context.User.Identity.Name).Id;
        db.Images.AddObject(image);
        foreach (NumericTag tag in tags.OfType<NumericTag>())
        {
            var numericTags = db.Tags.OfType<NumericTag>().Where(t => t.TagType.Id == tag.TagType.Id && t.Value == tag.Value);
            image.Tags.Add(numericTags.Any() ? numericTags.First() : new NumericTag
            {
                TagType = tag.TagType,
                Value = tag.Value
            });
        }
        foreach (TextualTag tag in tags.OfType<TextualTag>())
        {
            var textualTags = db.Tags.OfType<TextualTag>().Where(t => t.TagType.Id == tag.TagType.Id && t.Description == tag.Description);
            image.Tags.Add(textualTags.Any() ? textualTags.First() : new TextualTag
            {
                TagType = tag.TagType,
                Description = tag.Description
            });
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        detailsPanel.Visible = false;
        imagePanel.Visible = false;
        uploadPanel.Visible = true;
```

I'm trying to add attributes (tags) to an image as it is added to the database.  I have a temporary List of Tags stored in the ViewState.  When the line `image.Tags.Add` tries to add an existing tag, it works fine, but when it executes the initializer, it throws an "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager." exception.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

But this method from another page that adds tags to existing images in the database works fine:

```
TagType tagType = tagTypes[tagTypeDropDownList.SelectedIndex];
int numericTagValue;
if (tagType is NumericTagType & !int.TryParse(tagDecriptionTextBox.Text, out numericTagValue))
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "TagError",
        string.Format("alert('Only numeric values are valid for tags of type {0}.');", tagType.Name), true);
    return;
}
foreach (var imageId in imageCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected)
    .Select(i => int.Parse(i.Value)))
{
    var image = db.Images.First(i => i.Id == imageId);
    var tags = db.Tags.AsEnumerable().Where(t => t.TagType.Id == tagType.Id
                    && (t is TextualTag ?
                    ((TextualTag)t).Description == tagDecriptionTextBox.Text :
                    ((NumericTag)t).Value == numericTagValue));
    if (tags.Any())
    {
        var tag = tags.First();
        if (!image.Tags.Select(t => t.Id).Contains(tag.Id))
            image.Tags.Add(tag);
    }
    else
    {
        if (tagType is NumericTagType)
            image.Tags.Add(new NumericTag
                {
                    TagType = (NumericTagType)tagType,
                    Value = numericTagValue
                });
        else
            image.Tags.Add(new TextualTag
                {
                    TagType = (TextualTagType)tagType,
                    Description = tagDecriptionTextBox.Text
                });
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
attributeListView.DataBind();
tagDecriptionTextBox.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
new TextualTag
{
    TagType = tag.TagType,
    Description = tag.Description
});
```

doesn't grant object unicity. You have to specify a Primary Key for the new Tag.

If you're working with `Guids`, this is simple. `Guid.NewGuid()` resolves all the problem.

If you're using `int` with `Identity`, you'll need to make objects different from each other using another property.

Comment: I'm using an int primary key with Identity.  Why isn't that sufficient?  By the way `TextualTag` and `NumericTag` are subclasses of `Tag`.

Comment: Because if you insert two `TextualTag`s with the same `TagType` and `Description`, EF will not get to differ the two objects.

Comment: Isn't that what the identity field is for?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have the identity values only after calling `context.SaveChanges()`, because the numbers are generated by your database.

Comment: So where do I need to call `SaveChanges()`?  Inside the `foreach` loops?  I tried that resulting in the same outcome.

Comment: Yes, inside the `foreach`, but this can make a performance decrease.